# How can I add a vertex at the center of a circle?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have filled circle and I want to add vertex at center of it. After that I want to connect vertices from circle to the center vertex (this part I know how to do).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you've already added the circle there are some other fast ways to do this:

## Method 1:

1. Select the circle.
2. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>), then cancel the translate part of the extrusion with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Center* to merge the extruded vertices into a single central vertex.

   [image]

## Method 2:

1. Select the circle.
2. Fill (<kbd>F</kbd>) to make an n-gon.
3. Poke Faces (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) to triangulate the n-gon with a central vertex.

   [image]

Comment: Darn, I can't do screen capture gifs. Excellent answer!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Why not? LICEcap works just fine for me..

Answer (score 4):

You can do this when you first add the circle. When you first add the mesh, go to the tools where you normally enter the vertex number, and select *Fill Type > Triangle Fan*.

[image]

This will make a mesh like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is necessary to use an existing mesh, select all the vertices in the circle, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Selected*.

[image]

Then deselect all, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click anywhere in the viewport. This will add a vertex.

[image]

Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> *Selection to Cursor*. This will place it where the 3D cursor is located, which is in the exact center of the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Select the entire cicle <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>. in that order.

This will scale all vertices to 0.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> > <kbd>V</kbd> > *remove doubles*.
To make a master vertex at center, rather than all thirty-two occupying the same space.